# Moo: Add attribute to another (non-current) package

Tags: perl, attributes, moose, moo

The following is a simplified example of my real code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package X;
use Moo;

sub add_attr_for_another_package {
  my ($package) = @_;
  eval "package $package";
  has 'q' => (is=>'rw', default=>123);
}

package Y;
use Moo;

X::add_attr_for_another_package('Y');

my $obj = Y->new;
print $obj->q, "\n";
```

I try to add an attribute to package `Y` from a function defined in package `X`. This does not work:

```
$ ./test.pl 
Can't locate object method "q" via package "Y" at ./test.pl line 18.
```

Please help how can I add an attribute to a package from a method defined in another package.

Should I switch to Moose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`package` affects the package into which code is compiled. It obviously won't affect code that's already been compiled (e.g. the call to `has`)! In other words, the call to `has` has to be compiled when the `package` directive is in effect to be affected by it.

```
sub add_attr_for_another_package {
  my ($package) = @_;
  eval("
    package $package;
    has 'q' => (is=>'rw', default=>123);
    return 1;
  ")
    or die $@;
}
```